# How to force a change to og:title?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

We have monthly advertising campaigns, and for the last one, we setup the open graph tags and everything for proper facebook liking, but we always like the home page of the site.

Now, **it appears that the og:title tag is fixed.** I read somewhere that after 50 likes, it becomes fixed. We really, really need to change it though because it references our old advertising campaign that is no longer live.

Does anyone know of a way to force the og:title to be refreshed? We've even tried contacting facebook, but can't figure out how.

Note that the facebook debugger tool does not update our og:title, but it does update everything else correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook caches your og:meta tags. You can force a cache reset by visiting the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and entering your URL. It appears to process the URL via a GET variable, so you could probably automate this process.

In my experience, even pages with thousands of likes will update their title if the og:title tag is updated. It just takes more time.

If it isn't updating, are you sure you've got the correct information in your page's source and the debugger isn't throwing any errors? Also, are you sure that a local cache isn't serving outdated content?

Comment: The facebook debugger tool shows that it is getting all other meta tags correctly, except the og:title.

Comment: I can't help you more if you won't share more.

Comment: After considerable research today, I don't think there's any way you can help me more, and I can't share any more without people over here on my side getting uncomfortable. The problem seems to be what I described in my original question -- after 50 likes, the og:title becomes fixed. If you don't have specific knowledge about how to get around this, or how to contact Facebook, then you probably can't help. It's not a matter of errors with the open graph tags; everything is good according to the debugger. Thanks anyway.